# Solving differential equation - initial condition

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the differential equation:

```
DSolve[{R''[ρ] + 2 /ρ R'[ρ] + (1 - (l (l + 1))/ρ^2) R[ρ] == 0}, R[ρ], ρ]
```

This works fine and outputs:

```
{{R[ρ] -> C[1] SphericalBesselJ[l, ρ] + C[2] SphericalBesselY[l, ρ]}}
```

But when I add the condition:

```
R[0] ==0
```

i.e.

```
DSolve[{R''[ρ] + 2 /ρ R'[ρ]] + (1 - (l (l + 1))/ρ^2) R[ρ] == 0,
R[0] == SphericalBesselJ[1, 0]}, R[ρ], ρ]
```

The output is:

```
{ }
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: You have syntax errors. `DSolve[{R''[ρ] + 2 /ρ R'[ρ]] +` is not correct syntax. Did you copy this as is from your notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see why this happens if you evaluate your general result at zero :

```
     C[1] SphericalBesselJ[1, 0] + C[2] SphericalBesselY[1, 0]
```

> ComplexInfinity

while of course only one of the solutions is singular:

```
      {SphericalBesselJ[1, 0], SphericalBesselY[1, 0]}
```

> {0, ComplexInfinity}

So it seems `DSolve` simply tries to solve for `C[1],C[2]` to satisfy the b.c. and fails.

As to why `DSolve` isnt smart enough to discard the singular solution, that is a good question.

Note that it does solve this related system that shows the same issue with one singular solution that must be discarded.

```
 DSolve[ { R''[p] + (2 R'[p])/p - (2 R[p])/p^2 == 0 , R[0] == 0} , R[p], p]
```

> R[p] -> p C[1]

Here you get a warning

> is possible that some of the conditions have been specified at a singular point for the equation

(For the example I set `l=1` by the way. The unspecified parameter presents another potential issue but its not the cause of the problem here.)